# How to get the current default set language of the current Windows OS for version 7 and later versions using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How to get the current default set language of the current Windows OS for version 7 and later versions using C++?

To deal this, I've tried to look for in the net but without any result.

Any brilliant suggestion, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318122%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`GetUserDefaultLocaleName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318136%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the locale

Comment: I'm in fact trying to get the installed windows's set language and not the keyboard's set language.

Comment: @user3508865: why?  Surely the user's choice of locale is the one that matters?

Answer (score 0):

```
string const s = setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );
cout << s << endl;
```

… is one way.

---

**Update**: The above does not retrieve the “preferred” language set in the Control Panel. E.g. on my laptop it says Norwegian in spite of a preference for US English. Following the documentation I tried `GetSystemPreferredUILanguages`, but it still reported Norwegian. However, **`GetThreadUILanguage`** reports US English, so presumably that's it.

Comment: I'm in fact trying to get the installed windows's set language and not the keyboard's set language.

Comment: @user3508865: I see. On my laptop `setlocale` reports Norwegian, even though I have English as my preference for the UI. Lemme check more.